# mongodb embedded document search

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongodb collection like as follows . My job is to increase the "rate" of a particular document inside "ratings" key. I can do it by following command in mongo shell.  `db.amitava1.update({_id:1},{"$inc":{"ratings.0.rating":1 } } )` .                                                 . Here by 0 I access the first document in "ratings". But I need to use a variable in place of 0. The following does not work.

```
x = 0;
db.amitava1.update({_id:1},{"$inc":{"ratings.x.rating":1 } } );
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks,

Comment: try this:    db.amitava1.update({_id:1},{"$inc":{"ratings.rating":1 } } );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do it with [`Template String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings), to parse `x` in the `ratings.x.rating`.

```
> var x = 0;
> var str = `ratings.${x}.rating`;
> db.amitava1.update({_id:1}, {$inc: {[str]: 1}})
```

Comment: Hi zangw,many thanks. It worked!!! However if you also tell me how it works in python using pymongo, I would greatly appreciate. The problem happenned in pymongo, and I thought problem would be same in mongo shell also. But your code is not working in pymongo. And I am very new in mongodb, python. The error in python is as follows.

Comment: @AMITAVA, sorry, I have no pymongo currently... It sounds it is another question as you mentioned. please ask another different question with your issue with more details.